# Why wont my conditional loops function properly?

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

This is a hw problem to make a course registration program. I feel like i have most of the work done but I'm having trouble understanding why when in the second while loop if the choice value is set back to A it won't return to the add course loop.

```
choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
choice = choice.upper()

courses = []

while choice == "A":
    course1 = input("Enter a course to add: ")
    courses.append(course1)
    courses.sort()
    print("Courses Registered: ", courses)
    choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
    choice= choice.upper()
else:
    while choice == "D":
        drop1 = input("Enter a course to drop: ")
        if drop1 in courses:
            courses.remove(drop1)
            print("Course Dropped")
            courses.sort()
            print("Courses Registered: ", courses)
            choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
            choice = choice.upper()
        else:
            print("You are not registered in that class")
            choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
            choice = choice.upper()
    else:
        if choice == "E":
            print("You have exited the program")
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
            choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
            choice = choice.upper()
```

It works up until after I've dropped a class and want to go back to adding classes. Then it just continues in the code and will print the "Invalid input"

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` statement to terminate the `while loop`, else keep updating the choice

```
courses = []
choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
choice = choice.upper()

while True:
    if choice == "A":
        course1 = input("Enter a course to add: ")
        courses.append(course1)
        courses.sort()
        print("Courses Registered: ", courses)
        choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
        choice= choice.upper()
    elif choice == "D":
        drop1 = input("Enter a course to drop: ")
        if drop1 in courses:
            courses.remove(drop1)
            print("Course Dropped")
            courses.sort()
            print("Courses Registered: ", courses)
            choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
            choice = choice.upper()
        else:
            print("You are not registered in that class")
            choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
            choice = choice.upper()
    elif choice == "E":
        print("You have exited the program")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
        choice = choice.upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using a while/else construct. Your code exits after any invalid input, not repeats. The second loop only accepts D, not A. So, only use one loop

Try out the following structure

```
courses = []

while True:
    choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ").upper()
    if choice == "E":
        break
    elif choice == "A":
        course1 = input("Enter a course to add: ")
        courses.append(course1)
        courses.sort()
        print("Courses Registered: ", courses)
     elif choice == "D":
         print("drop")
     else:
         print("invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep executing if input is not `E/e`, so you should write this way.

```
choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
choice = choice.upper()

courses = []

while choice != "E":
  if choice == "A":
    course1 = input("Enter a course to add: ")
    courses.append(course1)
    courses.sort()
    print("Courses Registered: ", courses)
  elif choice == "D":
    drop1 = input("Enter a course to drop: ")
    if drop1 in courses:
      courses.remove(drop1)
      print("Course Dropped")
      courses.sort()
      print("Courses Registered: ", courses)
    else:
        print("You are not registered in that class")
  else:
    print("Invalid input")

  choice = input("Enter A to add course, D to drop course, and E to exit: ")
  choice = choice.upper()
else:
  print("You have exited the program")
```